# Using mysqldump bypassing password prompt error

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am running a shell script:

```
$ ./backup.sh user 'passW0rd' database
```

And in my backup.sh file, I have this:

```
DB_USER=$1
DB_PASS=$2
DB_NAME=$3

mysqldump --user=${DB_USER} --password=${DB_PASS} ${DB_NAME} > my_data_dump.sql
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'user'@'000.000....' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect..
```

Now I know that All credentials are correct because when I test it this way within my shell file, It works:

```
DB_USER=$1
#DB_PASS=$2 #added the password inline
DB_NAME=$3

mysqldump --user=${DB_USER} --password='passW0rd' ${DB_NAME} > my_data_dump.sql
```

What am I doing wrong and why can I not get the password passed via the bash command?

Comment: I just tried your backup.sh code, using `${DB_PASS}`, and it worked fine for me...  I am on Mint v18 Linux, bash 4.3.48

Comment: Inline works, but passing as option doesn’t seem to for me.  Do you think it is the quotes that throwing it off? But I need the quotes because certain passwords can fire commands if there aren’t any quotes around it.

Comment: In other words, you need `"--password=${DB_PASS}"` or `--password="${DB_PASS}"` for correct handling of some characters.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot so are you saying that i can pass 'passW0rd' into 
"--password=${DB_PASS}" with no problem? SO it would show as:

 `mysqldump --user=user --password=passW0rd database > my_data_dump.sql` and not: 
`mysqldump --user=user --password='passW0rd' database > my_data_dump.sql`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot @Nic3500 is it possible to pass something like this in the command instead? 
`$ ./backup.sh 'DB_USER=user' 'DB_PASS=passW0rd' 'DB_NAME=database'`